# Using set method on List<Integer> causes Unsupported Operation Exception

Tags: java, arrays, list, set

Im trying to create an 8 element list [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] and then change the value of given index using the .set method. However the code raises an exception.

```
import java.util.*;
public class HQ {

    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        List<Integer> quantity= Collections.nCopies(8, 0);
        quantity.set(0,1);
    }
}
```

I thought it would change the first element of quantity to be 1 and leave the rest as 0.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.set(AbstractList.java:132)
    at HQ.main(HQ.java:10)
```

Comment: If you poke around, you will find that a `CopiesList` is being returned.  `CopiesList#set` does exist, but this list is immutable, so you can't change anything.

Answer (score 3):

[Collections.nCopies](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies-int-T-) will return immutable list, so you can't modify it

> **Returns an immutable list consisting of n copies of the specified object.** The newly allocated data object is tiny (it contains a single reference to the data object). This method is useful in combination with the List.addAll method to grow lists. The returned list is serializable.

You can use `stream` to create mutable list with n copies

```
List<Integer> ints = IntStream.range(0, 7).map(i -> 0).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or just convert immutable list into mutable

```
 List<Integer> quantity1= Collections.nCopies(8, 0);
 List<Integer> quantity = new ArrayList<Integer>(quantity1);
```